# if else for try_files when URL parameter

Tags: nginx

I have a static mirror of a website which is good for all normal pages. But when ever a user fetches a page with a URL parameter I want it directly to try `@proxy` and not the local static file.

https://www.example.com/test.html?query=foobar
should fetch from `@proxy`
https://www.example.com/test.html
should first try to fetch from `$uri $uri.html $uri/`

Here is my current config:

```
root /var/www/www.example.com/mirror/current;

location / {
   expires 12h;
   add_header Cache-Control public

   try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @proxy;
}
```

Unfortunately this config delivers always the static page when there is one and doesn't take care about any URL parameters.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - If there is a parameter, use @proxy.

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = @proxy;

    if ($args != "") {
        return 404;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @proxy;
}
```